# Cannot resolve symbol 'Routes'

Tags: reactjs, pycharm, jsx

I am importing Routes the following way

```
import {Routes, Route, BrowserRouter} from 'react-router-dom'
```

My package JSON is `"react-router-dom": "^6.0.2",`

[image]

I am using Pycharm.

`npm list react-router-dom` returns `-- react-router-dom@6.0.2`

Why is this happening? My frontend is blank.

Comment: Check the installed version from the app directory `npm list react-router-dom`.

Comment: I get `-- react-router-dom@6.0.2`

Comment: I am using Pycharm BTW

Comment: If it's relevant then include that in your post.

Comment: Same is happening to me in IntelliJ even after deleting node_modules and the usual suspects.
When you cmd/ctrl-click "react-router-dom" IntelliJ show 2 possibilities; one cached and one in the node_modules. The one cached is still 5.3.2 for me. I'm thinking this is an IntelliJ issue.
Seeing as Pycharm has the same core..

Comment: May want to delete the `node_modules` directory, run `npm clear cache`, then `npm i` to reinstall all the dependencies.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

I had the exact same issue of "**Cannot Resolve Symbol**" for most of the **imports** in Intellij, when I upgraded to the `react-router-dom:6.0.2`.

As **@DLH** stated, the Jetbrains Product was **reading the type file** for the package from `<system directory>/jetbrains/intellij/javascript/typings` rather than from the `node_modules` folder of the project.

As said by **Oksana Chumak** from Jetbrains:

> The IDE downloads typings for some popular libraries to its configuration folder and uses them to enhance code completion.

### **Solution:**

1. Inside the jetbrains product, press **shift two times** to open the search everywhere window, search for **registry** and open the first result.
2. In the registry, look for **typescript.external.type.defintions.packages** key and in the *value* of that field, **only remove** the **react-router-dom** field from the values.
3. Also Go to File -> Invalidate Caches -> select "Clear file system cache and Local History" -> click "Invalidate and Restart"

Now, the *jetbrains product* will **read the type file** from `node_modules` of project,  rather than reading it from its `internal typings folder`. In the future, It will also **not try to download and use** the **intellij react-router-dom typings** for other projects.

Credits: Props to @Mir-Ismaili and @unfestive chicken for helping out  with the third step.

Comment: Thanks. I needed to restart the IDE too.

Comment: where can I find internal typings folder on macOS?

Comment: On mac, I just File -> Invalidate Caches -> select "Clear file system cache and Local History" -> click "Invalidate and Restart"

Comment: Very helpful. Also, I believe 3rd step can be replaced with File > Invalidate Caches > Clear file system cache & Mark downloaded shared indexes excluded.

Comment: On Mac it can be fixed by removing react-router-dom from registry.  Registry is located via: Help > Find action > type Registry, and edit typescript.external.type.definitions

Comment: FYI: On Linux, remove "typescript.external.type.defintions.packages" from Registry and then "File -> Invalidate Caches -> select "Clear file system cache and Local History" -> click "Invalidate and Restart"

Comment: @unfestivechicken Your solution is the proper one. You should consider adding it as a response.

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same problem in WebStorm. When I did the crtl-click over `'react-router-dom'` in the import statement, I saw that it seemed to be confused over which index.ts.d file to pay attention to. One was from the 6.0.2 version installed in my project's node_modules as expected. The other was in C:\Users[me]\AppData\Local\JetBrains\WebStorm2021.2\javascript\typings\react-router-dom\5.3.2\node_modules@types\react-router-dom\index.d.ts.

I just renamed the latter JetBrains file from 5.3.2 figuring that it was now obsolete, and it worked as expected thereafter. It's not the prettiest solution, and I'm only mostly sure that it won't find a way to bite me in the rump later. But at least for now, it works.

Answer (score 1):

On macOS, a possible solution is this:

In your app bar, press File -> Invalidate Caches -> select "Clear file system cache and Local History" -> click "Invalidate and Restart"

Answer (score 0):

We can try removing `node_modules` and deleting that folder.
Then we can run `npm` this will reinstall those packages again.

After that, I would then try implement the `Router` and see if it resolves itself even though it complains that it can't find the symbol.

Something like this should work:

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Routes>
    <Route path='/*' element={ <App /> } />
  </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the blank screen, it was because of the version so I had to change the code based on https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/main/docs/getting-started/tutorial.md, but I still have a warning "Cannot resolve symbol 'Routes'"I'm using the latest version of Webstrom.

```
import React from "react";
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import { Container } from "react-bootstrap";
import Header from "./components/Header";
import Footer from "./components/Footer";
import HomeScreen from "./screens/HomeScreen";

const  App = () => {
  return(
    <Router>
      <Header />
      <main className='py-3'>
          <Container>
              <Routes>
                  <Route exact path="/" element={<HomeScreen />}/>
              </Routes>
          </Container>
      </main>
      <Footer />
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to install Typescript stubs for the package

You have two options:

1. Install it with IDE

- Put cursor on "react-router-dom" in import statement
- hit Alt+Enter
- choose Install TypeScript definitions for better type information

[image: Install TypeScript definitions]

2. Install it with npm

- open cmd at your project
- npm install @types/react-router-dom

Don't forget to remove IDE library from Preferences | Languages & Frameworks | JavaScript | Libraries , if you used option 1